# C# CsvHelper: WriteRecord throws "ConfigurationException: Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped"

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

This is my original code, writing to a CSV file without CsvHelper.

```
 public static void Write(string file, List<PayRecord> payrecords) {
   using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file)) {
     sw.WriteLine("EmployeeId,Gross,Tax,Net");
     foreach(PayRecord c in payrecords) {
       string line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",
         c.Id,
         c.Gross,
         c.Tax,
         c.Net);
       sw.WriteLine(line);
     }
   }
 }
```

This is the same code, however using CsvHelper this time:

```
public static void Write(string file, List<PayRecord> payrecords)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        cw.WriteHeader<PayRecord>();
        foreach (var c in payrecords)
        {
            string line = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3}",
                c.Id,
                c.Gross,
                c.Tax,
                c.Net);
            cw.WriteRecord(line);

        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting exceptions like:

```
Unhandled exception. CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationException: Types that inherit IEnumerable cannot be auto mapped. Did you accidentally call GetRecord or WriteRecord which acts on a single record instead of calling GetRecords or WriteRecords which acts on a list of records?
   at CsvHelper.CsvWriter.WriteRecord[T](T record)
```

and:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap.AutoMapConstructorParameters(ClassMap map, CsvContext context, LinkedList`1 mapParents, Int32 indexStart)
   at CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap.AutoMapConstructorParameters(ClassMap map, CsvContext context, LinkedList`1 mapParents, Int32 indexStart)
   at CsvHelper.Configuration.ClassMap.AutoMap(CsvContext context)
   at CsvHelper.CsvContext.AutoMap(Type type)
   at CsvHelper.CsvWriter.WriteHeader(Type type)
   at CsvHelper.CsvWriter.WriteHeader[T]()
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Can you also please share your `PayRecord` class please?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing strings to the csv file, not sure exactly what you gained by switching to CsvHelper here as you seem to be doing all the work yourself still. Instead you should write the actual objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You're trying to write a `string` as a record.**

`cw.WriteRecord(line);`

There's no way I've been able to reproduce your `ArgumentNullException` but I do know that even with that fixed, your code still won't work.

The above will throw a `CsvHelper.Configuration.ConfigurationException` as a `string` is classed as a single field & `CsvHelper.WriteRecord` is more for a class as opposed to a `string`.

Secondly, `CsvWriter.WriteHeader` will not move the "cursor" to the next row so you need to use `CsvWriter.NextRecord()` otherwise your data will all be on the same line as your header.

The below code works:

```
  public static void Write(string file, List<PayRecord> payrecords) {
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    using(CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)) {
      cw.WriteHeader<PayRecord>();
      cw.NextRecord();

      foreach(var c in payrecords) {
        cw.WriteRecord(c);
      }
    }
}
```

---

**However**, even better would be to not write the header manually, use `CsvHelper.WriteRecords` and pass the entire collection of objects like below.

This results in smaller, cleaner & more efficient code using `CsvHelper.WriteRecords` correctly, while also writing the correct header.

This is *better*:

```
public static void Write(string file, List<PayRecord> payrecords)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        cw.WriteRecords(payrecords);
    }
}
```

---

**Even better?**

To perform I/O operations (writing to the CSV file) without blocking the main thread, use `CsvHelper.WriteRecordsAsync`, use `await using` to not block on resource cleanup & make your method `async` to be able to `await` the call.

I'd also use `ICollection<PayRecord>` so that if you ever change `List<PayRecord>` to any other type which implements `ICollection`, you won't need to change the method.

*Crème de la crème*:

```
public static async Task WritePayRecords(string file, ICollection<PayRecord> payrecords)
{
    await using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(file))
    await using (CsvWriter cw = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture))
    {
        if (payrecords == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(payrecords), "Collection of pay records cannot be null");

        await cw.WriteRecordsAsync(payrecords);
    }
}
```

The code above will work even with `null` fields, `null` objects and will also throw an exception if the collection is `null` (as otherwise, CsvHelper will throw one).

Hope that helps!

Comment: "foreach(var c in payrecords) {
        cw.WriteRecord(line);
      }" doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Thanks for pointing out the typo - fixed :)